# Is it possible to create a route like '~:id' in Rails 2.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have been using the following route successfully in my Rails 2.x application:

```
map.user ':id', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

This, as my lowest route, properly catches things like `/tsmango` and renders `Users#show`.

I'm now trying to add a second, similar route like:

```
map.post '~:id', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show'
```

Because neither my users or my posts are allowed to contain ~ *and because this route will appear above my map.user route*, I assumed this would properly catch any call starting with `/~` and render my `Posts#show` action. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble getting this one to work.

What's interesting is that this similar route works perfectly:

```
map.post ':id~', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show'
```

Although, I'm certainly willing to go with `':id~'` since it has the same result, at this point I'm really just frustrated and curious as to how you would build a route that matches `'~:id'`.

It's worth mentioning that I do not want to modify my to_param method or my actual user and post slugs to include the prepended ~. I just want that in a route to indicate which action should handle it. Unless I'm mistaken, this rules out the use of something like:

```
:requirements => {:id => /\~[a-zA-Z0-9]/}
```

Thanks, in advance, for any help you can provide!

**Update:** I'm aware of route priority and stated above that I am placing the `'~:id'` route above the `':id'` route. I receive the following error while trying to generate the url like `post_path(@post)`:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.to_sym
```

Answer (score 1):

Routes are prioritized depending of the order in which they're declared.
When you define first the :id route, the second one is never executed.

In order for this to work, you just have to first define the ~:id route and then the :id one.

```
map.post '~:id', :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show'
map.post ':id',  :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

Comment: Yep, I know they are prioritized. I mentioned above that I'm placing the '~:id' route above the ':id' route, but I'm still unable to make that work.

I'm receiving this error:

    You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! The error occurred while evaluating nil.to_sym

When I try and use the route like:

    link_to('Test', post_path(@post))